# Magento Convert currency_id(int) into currency code(str)

Tags: magento

I have an custom attribute called cl_wholesaleunitprice_currency which returns an Id of a currency, such as 553,554,556. [from eav_attributes]

These relate to the currency codes 'EUR', 'USD' and 'GBP' respectively.

I am having a hard time finding out how I retrieve the currency code from the currency id since I can't find the related table.

My searches have lead nowhere since they are getting clouded other questions, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instead of saving the currency id, save currency code directly.. because in magento all the currency related functionality are working based on the currency code.

Comment: @Prasath Albert unfortunately I am building on top of someone elses work, I do agree though it does seem like a bizarre way to store the currency identifier.

Comment: are you sure that 553, 554, 556 are currency ids?

Comment: @PrasathAlbert that is a very good point, they definitely relate to an currency attribute, but in all possibility they could just be a custom identifier. The ids are converted at a point, I am just trying to find  that point in the the code.

Comment: Since the attribute was using EAV I had to use the following code to get the text value of the the _id `$product->getAttributeText('cl_wholesaleunitprice_currency')`  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was an EAV attribute I used

```
$product->getAttributeText('cl_wholesaleunitprice_currency')
```

to get the text value of the ids